# UWP Tab View not responding

Tags: c#, uwp, tabview

I have a page with a Tab View. Inside every tab is another page. Whenever I try to interact with the tab, nothing works. I tried interacting with it with SettingsPage as the content, and it worked.

MainPage - contains the tabs

TabbedMainPage - contains the workspace

SettigsPage - contains settings

MainPage:

```
    private void TabView_AddTabButtonClick(TabView sender, object args)
    {
        sender.TabItems.Add(CreateNewTab());
    }

    public TabViewItem OpenSettingsTab()
    {
        TabViewItem newItem = new TabViewItem();
        newItem.Header = "Settings";
        newItem.IconSource = new Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.SymbolIconSource() { Symbol = Symbol.Setting };
        Frame frame = new Frame();
        frame.Navigate(typeof(SettingsPage));
        newItem.Content = frame;
        TabbedView.UpdateLayout();
        return newItem;
    }

    public void CreateSettingsTab()
    {
        TabbedView.TabItems.Add(OpenSettingsTab());
        TabbedView.UpdateLayout();
        TabbedView.SelectedIndex = TabbedView.TabItems.Count - 1;
    }

    public TabViewItem CreateNewTab()
    {
        TabViewItem newItem = new TabViewItem();
        newItem.Header = "New Tab";
        newItem.IconSource = new Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.SymbolIconSource() { Symbol = Symbol.Document };
        Frame frame = new Frame();
        frame.Navigate(typeof(TabbedMainPage));
        newItem.Content = frame;
        TabbedView.UpdateLayout();
        return newItem;
    }

    private void TabbedView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var S = sender as TabView;
        if (S.TabItems.Count == 0)
        {
            S.TabItems.Add(CreateNewTab());
        }
        TabbedView.UpdateLayout();
    }
```

TabbedMainPage has the following components: ColorPicker, DropDownButton, MenuBar, Border, Button, CheckBox, ComboBox, Flyout, Grid, Image, MenuFlyout, Pivot, PivotItem, StackPanel, TextBlock, TextBox, Flyout, Popup, RichEditBox, ScrollViewer, Slider, ToggleButton and Tooltip.

I think it might be caused by overloading with components, but I'm not sure. I also have these in my code:

```
    MediaElement ME;

    SpeechSynthesizer Synth;

    public StorageFile TXTFile;

    public IRandomAccessStream RAS;

    private readonly PrintHelperOptions PP = new PrintHelperOptions();

    var LS = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;

    var TB = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TitleBar;

    var CTB = CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar;
```

Comment: I used your code and used the controls and components (except `PrintHelperOptions`) you listed in the `TabbedMainPage` and everything works fine. The problem cannot be reproduced according to the code provided so far. For better troubleshooting, could you reproduce your problem in a blank project and share the code?

Comment: You can reproduce your problem in a blank project, and update the code on this question or share the code using GitHub.

Comment: I used the code you provided, and it didn't reproduce successfully, so there may be a problem with the part other than the code you provided. For better troubleshooting, please provide a sample that reproduces your problem.

Comment: I downloaded the project you shared and reproduced what you said, and I am troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix the bug by removing the Pivot from the toolbar. It was interfering with the tab functionality, so I merged all the items together.